# getting Name error while using Super method

Tags: python, super

I tried one sample code with Super method.
But I get errored out.

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
    def fullname(self):
        print(firstname, ' ', lastname)

class student(person):
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, grade):
        self.grade = grade
        super().__init__(firstname, lastname) # calling base constructor
    def display_details(self):
        super().fullname() # calling base class method
        print('Grade ', self.grade)
    
std = student('James', 'Bond', '10')
std.display_details()
```

Error:
print(firstname, ' ', lastname)
NameError: name 'firstname' is not defined

Comment: In `fullname` method you need to refer to instance attributes, i.e. `self.firstname` and `self.lastname`

Comment: Of course, *those variables are not in scope anywhere*. Note, this has **nothing** to do with super. If you ust did `person('foo', 'bar').fullname()` you would get the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

In the person class, in method fullname, firstname and lastname is not defined. You have taken those arguments in the init method, but not in the fullname method. You can use the object variables for that which you have defined in the init method.

```
print(self.firstname, ' ', self.lastname)
```